# Paypal recurring payment without billing cycle

Tags: php, paypal

I want to implement paypal recurring payment without any specific billing cycle.
Consider this scenario:
customer buys a service from my account which is charged on usage basis for example downloading content from site. Here's what I want to:
1)  Customer get authorized by paypal whenever s/he chooses paypal at my site.
2) Billing starts when customer first download content from my site.
3) Recurring payment whenever the data limit of user is about to cross the maximum threshold for example 1 GB.

So there is no fixed billing cycle and same authorization for all recurring payments until user chooses to stop paypal as payment option.

Is there any feature on paypal that supports this type of tranzactions.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in your scenario the billing cycle and the time period is not fixed you can make use of PayPal reference transaction where you will create a billing agreement with customer and then for all the future payments you can use that billing agreement Id to charge the customer at per their usage for any amount . You can find more information here :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

And at later time if your customer wants to cancel the agreement they can cancel it from their PayPal account or you can use API's to cancel it .

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for, Also, is it possible to authorize user for reference tranzaction without redirecting to paypal' site. I want to use express checkout only

Comment: No. If somebody pays through the PayPal they will have to login to the PayPal account to agree the billing agreement . Once they authorize it then only you will be able to use the reference transaction .